# Use javascript string in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a string in javaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Var string='String to use';
</script>
```

Now i want to access text of string in php.
How can i access it. Or use it.

Comment: `var` should be written in lowercase

Comment: so the javascript is getting executed on the client's computer and you are asking how you can use a specific stringm from the client's computer, in your php code that gets executed on your server...you need to establish some communication between the two...look into ajax or $_POST or $_GET...if it's a static string, define it in your php and pass it to javascript...

Comment: Is this string known when generating the initial page?  If is is static like you are showing it, then why don't you already know the value?

Comment: you can not assign JS variable directly in PHP since your PHP will execute before JS. However u can use AJAX to pass the variable to PHP. A php data however could be assigned to JS directly.

Comment: One way to think about this problem is to ask it another way like "how do I access a variable in my xBox on my laptop" the answer is "by passing it over the network".  JavaScript (in this case, forget things like node.js for now) runs entirely on the client while PHP (ignore projects like php.js for now as well) run on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to make an `ajax` call if you don't want to reload the page else add it to a `hidden` `form` `field` and `submit`. I usually do it in jQuery like this-

```
    $.ajax({
    url:"demo_test.txt",
    data:{
    variable_name_in_php_script:variable_name_in_javascript
    }
    success:function(result){
//process result
        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this might be of help to you. I hope everything works out.

http://w3epic.com/how-to-pass-variable-from-php-to-javascript-javascript-to-php/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.